# The subscript size for formulas in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, subscripts, size

First of all sorry because this question may be duplicated. I don't know why the question was uploaded with another user's name and I can't edit it (may be you can delete the previous question with the same title). The question is the following:

I am creating a beamer presentation where I have a lot of formulas. Between the packages used I have `\usepackage{amsmath}` and the theme for the presentation is `\usetheme{Warsaw}`.

As it can be seen in the attached picture, the size of the sub(super)script is bigger than the normal writting.

[image]

**Anyone knows a set of basic packages in order to get the classical formulas, without these size changes?**

The code is the following

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}


%--------------------------%
% To add enumeration index
%--------------------------%
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber 
}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}


%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}



% Theme for the presentation
\usetheme{Warsaw}
% Change the colour
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}  % Delete the footline with the names



\begin{document}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textbf{Algorithm}: step \texttt{s}}


\scriptsize

\textbf{STEP \texttt{s}}

\vspace{0.25cm}

Let $B^{(s-1)}$ be the variable  for the $\mathit{(s-1)}$-th step, let's take the sets $I_+^{(s-1)}$ and $I_-^{(s-1)}$ of length $r_+^{(s-1)}$ and $r_-^{(s-1)}$ respectively,and define:\\

\vspace{0.25cm}

\begin{center}

$B^{(s+)}= \sqrt{\tfrac{(r_+^{(s-1)} + 1)*r_-^{(s-1)}}{r_+^{(s-1)} + r_-^{(s-1)} + 1}} $

\end{center}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have added the output image for the code. I had some problems adding yesterday and that is why I added another with the same format.

Answer (score 3):

The subscripts and superscripts are smaller, but not so much as the main parts of the fraction is typeset in script style because of `\tfrac`.

You're making a couple of mistakes:

1. you're using `center` instead of `equation*`
2. you're using `\tfrac` instead of `\frac`

Here's the frame text. Notice the higher level `\bigskip` rather than an explicit length. Never use `\\` for ending paragraphs. Are you really sure about `\scriptsize`?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textbf{Algorithm}: step \texttt{s}}

\scriptsize% ???

\textbf{STEP \texttt{s}}

\bigskip

Let $B^{(s-1)}$ be the variable for the $(s-1)$-th step, let's take the sets 
$I_+^{(s-1)}$ and $I_-^{(s-1)}$ of length $r_+^{(s-1)}$ and $r_-^{(s-1)}$ 
respectively, and define:
\begin{equation*}
B^{(s+)}= \sqrt{\frac{(r_+^{(s-1)} + 1)*r_-^{(s-1)}}{r_+^{(s-1)} + r_-^{(s-1)} + 1}}
\end{equation*}

\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The `\scriptsize` is due to the code is a subset of the global content and I reduced the size in order to put all the text inside.

Comment: @R18 Remember you're doing a presentation and that your audience will be annoyed by squeezing too much text in a slide.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I am thinking to reduce as many as possible the content, but formulas and notation are not helpful, XD.